# Can't delete mysql matches when one row is empty

Tags: mysql

I have some tables with "temp" column, I want to delete all rows when "temp" number matches but I if I have one table that doesn't match with the where clause mysql says that query is ok but returns 0 matches and  dont deletes all the other coincidences.
This is my query:

```
DELETE IGNORE jornadas,ejerciciosnb,wodsnb,sailkapena,puntostotales FROM jornadas 
INNER JOIN ejerciciosnb 
INNER JOIN wodsnb 
INNER JOIN sailkapena 
INNER JOIN puntostotales 
WHERE puntostotales.temp=sailkapena.temp 
AND jornadas.temp=sailkapena.temp 
AND jornadas.temp=ejerciciosnb.temp 
AND jornadas.temp=wodsnb.temp 
AND jornadas.temp=3 
AND jornadas.bid=94;
```

In my case, "sailkapena" can be empty some times... how can I delete all of other coincidences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN`s instead, and please, properly use the `ON` clause :

```
DELETE IGNORE jornadas,ejerciciosnb,wodsnb,sailkapena,puntostotales
FROM jornadas 
LEFT JOIN ejerciciosnb 
 ON jornadas.temp=ejerciciosnb.temp 
LEFT JOIN wodsnb 
 ON jornadas.temp=wodsnb.temp 
LEFT JOIN sailkapena 
 ON jornadas.temp=sailkapena.temp 
LEFT JOIN puntostotales 
 ON  puntostotales.temp=jornadas.temp 
WHERE jornadas.temp=3 
  AND jornadas.bid=94;
```